# Sorting multiple arrays either alphabetically or in descending order

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, alphabetical

This program is supposed to accept a student's last name (LN), first name (FN), middle initial (MI), address (ADD), first, second, third, and fourth quarter grades (FIR, SEC, THR, FTH), compute for the average of the four inputted grades, and display all the info either alphabetically (last names) or descending order (averages).

It is supposed to look like this:

```
.
.    Last name:                 First name:                 Middle Intial:     Address:
.
.                   First Quarter grades:
.                   Second Quarter grades:
.                   Third Quarter grades:
.                   Fourth Quarter grades:
.                   Average:
.
.    Which way do you want to arrange the names? Enter A to alphabetize or B to arrange in descending order by grade.
```

After that, it should clear the screen and only display the names.

```
.
.    List:
.
.    Apple, Johnny K. from Kansas 89 91 89 91 90.0
.    Graham, Crackers L. from N.Y. 79 81 79 81 80.0
.
```

It is actually supposed to accept 90 students but I set 3 as a test number.

After inputting all the data, it will end saying "segmentation fault".

Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Should I use puts instead of printf in the last part? If so, how do I do that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
int a=0, SW=1, x, y, i, j, FIR[100], SEC[100], THR[100], FTH[100], AVE[100], sum=0, temp2[100];
char LN[15][90], FN[15][90], MI[5][90], ADD[50][90], OPT, temp1[50];
while(SW)
{
    clrscr();
    sum=0;

    gotoxy(10,2);
    printf("Family name: ");
    gotoxy(35,2);
    printf("First name: ");
    gotoxy(60,2);
    printf("Middle initial: ");
    gotoxy(80,2);
    printf("Address: ");
    gotoxy(25,4);
    printf("1st Quarter Grade: ");
    gotoxy(25,5);
    printf("2nd Quarter Grade: ");
    gotoxy(25,6);
    printf("3rd Quarter Grade: ");
    gotoxy(25,7);
    printf("4th Quarter Grade: ");
    gotoxy(25,8);
    printf("Average: ");
    gotoxy(23,2);
    fgets(LN[a],15,stdin);
    gotoxy(47,2);
    fgets(FN[a],15,stdin);
    gotoxy(76,2);
    fgets(MI[a],15,stdin);
    gotoxy(89,2);
    fgets(ADD[a],15,stdin);
    gotoxy(44,4); 
    scanf("%d",&FIR[a]);
    sum+=FIR[a];
    gotoxy(44,5);
    scanf("%d",&SEC[a]);
    sum+=SEC[a];
    gotoxy(44,6);
    scanf("%d",&THR[a]);
    sum+=THR[a];
    gotoxy(44,7);
    scanf("%d",&FTH[a]);
    sum+=FTH[a];
    AVE[a]=(float)sum/4;
    gotoxy(34,8);
    printf("%d",AVE[a]);
    a++;
    if(a==3)
        SW=0;
    getch();    
}        
gotoxy(10,10);
printf("Which way do you want to arrange the names? Enter A to alphabetize or B to arrange in descending order by grade. ");
gotoxy(10,11);
scanf("%c",&OPT);
if(OPT=='A' || OPT=='a')
{
    for(x=0;x<=2;x++){
        for(y=x+1;y<=2;y++){
            if(strcmp(LN[x],LN[y])>0){
                strcpy(temp1, LN[x]);
                strcpy(LN[x], LN[y]);
                strcpy(LN[y], temp1);
                strcpy(temp1, FN[x]);
                strcpy(FN[x], FN[y]);
                strcpy(FN[y], temp1);
                strcpy(temp1, MI[x]);
                strcpy(MI[x], MI[y]);
                strcpy(MI[y], temp1);
                strcpy(temp1, ADD[x]);
                strcpy(ADD[x], ADD[y]);
                strcpy(ADD[y], temp1);
                strcpy(temp2, FIR[x]);
                strcpy(FIR[x], FIR[y]);
                strcpy(FIR[y], temp2);
                strcpy(temp2, SEC[x]);
                strcpy(SEC[x], SEC[y]);
                strcpy(SEC[y], temp2);
                strcpy(temp2, THR[x]);
                strcpy(THR[x], THR[y]);
                strcpy(THR[y], temp2);
                strcpy(temp2, FTH[x]);
                strcpy(FTH[x], FTH[y]);
                strcpy(FTH[y], temp2);
                strcpy(temp2, AVE[x]);
                strcpy(AVE[x], AVE[y]);
                strcpy(AVE[y], temp2);
            }
        }
    }
}    
else
{
    for(x=0;x<=2;x++){
        for(y=x+1;x<=2;x++){
            if(AVE[x]<AVE[y]){
                strcpy(temp1, LN[x]);
                strcpy(LN[x], LN[y]);
                strcpy(LN[y], temp1);
                strcpy(temp1, FN[x]);
                strcpy(FN[x], FN[y]);
                strcpy(FN[y], temp1);
                strcpy(temp1, MI[x]);
                strcpy(MI[x], MI[y]);
                strcpy(MI[y], temp1);
                strcpy(temp1, ADD[x]);
                strcpy(ADD[x], ADD[y]);
                strcpy(ADD[y], temp1);
                strcpy(temp2, FIR[x]);
                strcpy(FIR[x], FIR[y]);
                strcpy(FIR[y], temp2);
                strcpy(temp2, SEC[x]);
                strcpy(SEC[x], SEC[y]);
                strcpy(SEC[y], temp2);
                strcpy(temp2, THR[x]);
                strcpy(THR[x], THR[y]);
                strcpy(THR[y], temp2);
                strcpy(temp2, FTH[x]);
                strcpy(FTH[x], FTH[y]);
                strcpy(FTH[y], temp2);
                strcpy(temp2, AVE[x]);
                strcpy(AVE[x], AVE[y]);
                strcpy(AVE[y], temp2);
            }
        }
    }
}
gotoxy(10,15);
printf("List: ");
for(j=17;j<=19;j++){
    for(x=0;x<=2;x++){
    i=10;
    gotoxy(i,j);
    printf("%s,%s %s",LN[x],FN[x],MI[x]);
    i+=40;
    gotoxy(i,j);
    printf("%f",FIR[x]);
    i+=5;
    gotoxy(i,j);
    printf("%f",SEC[x]);
    i+=5;
    gotoxy(i,j);
    printf("%f",THR[x]);
    i+=5;
    gotoxy(i,j);
    printf("%f",FTH[x]);
    i+=5;
    gotoxy(i,j);
    printf("%f",AVE[x]);
    i+=5;
    gotoxy(i,j);
    printf("from %s",ADD[x]);
    }
}
```

}

Edit: **I have no idea what I'm doing. I'm just trying to pass 8th grade Computer Science.**

Comment: I see strcpy is applied to an integer array (multiple times) which is possibly incorrect.

Comment: noted. how am i supposed to correct that?

Comment: `FIR[x] = FIR[y]`.

Comment: Step 1 with any user input issue: Check the return value from user input functions like `fgets()`, `scanf()`.

Comment: As a note of style, do not write in ALLCAPS variable names unless they are constants or macros

Comment: "to accept 90 students ", yet code uses `char LN[15][90]`, which would be for 15 students with a last name up to 89 characters.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp tried. it said there was an error and it pointed to the '='

Comment: @stackptr noted! thanks

Comment: @chux checked! all return values are correct. and changed the code for the names.

Comment: @M.Salipuran Code, like `scanf("%d",&FIR[a]);`  does not check the return value of any input function.  `if (scanf("%d",&FIR[a]) == 1) Proceed_with_success() else fail();` is an example of code checking the return value.

Comment: @chux i may or may not have understood your first comment and did not want to ignore it so i may or may not have lied about checking all the return values (i only checked some i'm sorry!)

Comment: if it isn't obvious already, i just started learning computer science last year, and that was 7th grade. i would appreciate it if you think an 8th grader will understand what you re about to comment first. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This program is supposed to accept a student's last name (LN), first name (FN), middle initial (MI), address (ADD), first, second, third, and fourth quarter grades (FIR, SEC, THR, FTH), compute for the average of the four inputted grades, and display all the info either alphabetically (last names) or descending order (averages).

The design you currently use is unmaintainable and disorganized. It sounds like you need to use a stucture to represent a student:

```
#define MAX_LNAME    80
#define MAX_FNAME    32
#define MAX_ADDRESS  128

typedef struct {
    char lname[MAX_LNAME];
    char fname[MAX_FNAME];
    char address[MAX_ADDRESS];
    double fir, sec, thr, fth;
} student;
```

And then a few functions that will manipulate or create `student` structures

```
student mkstudent(char *lname, char *fname, char *address, 
                  double fir, double sec, double thr, double fth)
{
    student ret;

    strcpy(ret.lname, lname);
    strcpy(ret.fname, fname);
    strcpy(ret.address, address);
    ret.fir = fir; ret.sec = sec; ret.thr = thr; ret.fth = fth;

    return ret;
}
double getAve(const student *s)
{
    return (s->fir + s->sec + s->thr + s->fth) / 4.;
}
void print(const student *s)
{
    printf("%s, %s from %s: %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf\n", s->lname, s->fname, 
               s->address, s->fir, s->sec, s->thr, s->fth, getAve(s));
}
```

Your program asks to sort the students, so you will need to use `qsort` (from `<stdlib.h>`)

```
int sortAlpha(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return strcmp( ((const student *) a)->lname, 
                   ((const student *) b)->lname );
}

int sortAves(const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
    const student *a = (const student *) pa;
    const student *b = (const student *) pb;

    double aAve = getAve(a), bAve = getAve(b);

    if (aAve == bAve) return 0;
    if (aAve > bAve) return -1;
    if (aAve < bAve) return 1;
}

#define SORT_LNAME 0    /* sort by last name */
#define SORT_AVES  1    /* sort by average, in descending order */

/* howSort will be one of the two macros defined above */
void sort(students *roster, size_t n, int howSort)
{
    if (howSort == SORT_LNAME)
        qsort(roster, n, sizeof *roster, sortAlpha);
    else (howSort == SORT_AVES)
        qsort(roster, n, sizeof *roster, sortAves);
}
```

Now that you have this interface written, you can write your main function by calling various routines that are implemented above

```
int main()
{
    /* array of student structures, possibly read them in from a file, 
       possibly print them, then ask user how to sort, etc. */
}
```

Comment: thank you! i don't understand it but that's what makes me even more grateful

Comment: @M.Salipuran Where are you confused?

Comment: the whole thing actually. the program i made was the best i can do. i just want to know what i went wrong in the program i made for our quiz tomorrow